# Laravel - npm run watch - runs repeatedly - nonstop

Tags: laravel, npm

I have installed Laravel. I use the Visual Studio Code to develop on my Windows 10. I have installed the npm and node. And ran install based on Laravel's default `package.json`, using `npm install` command.
I kept the file unchanged, and it looks like this:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^3.2.3",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "laravel-mix": "0.*",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "vue": "^2.1.10"
  }
}
```

The problem is, that running `npm run watch`, does not just make the npm wait for changes. npm runs the `npm run dev` all the time, over and over again!

Comment: What do you mean by running out of control?

Comment: maybe this edit helps make things clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper answer to this issue was addressed here

https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/228

It also has solution to resolve it and what causes it.

Comment: I don't have the build anymore, to test, but that seems to be the solution! Tnx.

Answer (score 3):

i had same issue and it's because i placed my image into `public/images` directory and this path was loading into my sass file. when i changed image path , that's worked fine

This issue happen's when you placed your assets into build path.

Answer (score 2):

This issue seems like it can have multiple error sources. In my case I it was relevant to **Tailwind CSS** and the `purge` option. I don't remember exactly what package I have installed but I copy pasted the following to my `tailwind.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'jit',
    purge: {
        content: [
            './public/**/*.html',
```

After I have removed the line `'./public/**/*.html',` it worked.

Answer (score -1):

npm run watch constantly running. Normal? yes its normal

use `npm run development` instead of `npm run watch`

`npm run watch` used for tracking your changes in css and js files then deploy it immediately

but `npm run development` deploy it once for development
and `npm run production` for production (minified files)

Comment: I want it to "track my changes in css and js files then deploy it immediately"

Comment: And probably not normal. It should run only when I change a file. but it is constantly running.

Comment: I know it consuming too much CPU and Memory, but in your case you must use it.

Comment: you are right its not running until you made a change

Comment: @MakanTayebi did you find any solution for this? Me too struggling with this issue!

Comment: I'm sorry, but No, I'm gonna rephrase the title, in case people  don't get it.